# Proof is too long; page-breaking issues

Tags: environments, page-breaking

I'm trying to write a paper for a specific journal (I'm using their preset), but I'm facing two problems regarding the main proof. Firstly if the proof is not short enough a page break is forced and the proof will start on the next page (regarding the theorem it corresponds to). Also if the proof is long enough, for some reason the margins are ignored and the proof keeps being rendered on the same page, and it doesn't continues rendering on the next page, which is even weirder.

Here's the code (sorry for the unnecessary packages, I didn't want to leave anything potentially relevant behind):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}    
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvips,dvipdfm]{graphicx}    
\usepackage{amsmath,latexsym,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage[sans]{dsfont}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage[sf,sl,outermarks]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[small,sc,bf,hang]{caption}
\usepackage{float,subfigure}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[sort&compress,square,comma,numbers]{natbib}

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\Large\sffamily}{\thesection}{0.5cm}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries\large\sffamily}{\thesubsection}{0.5cm}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\bfseries\normalsize\sffamily}{\thesubsubsection}{0.5cm}{}

\geometry{a4paper,right=2cm,left=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,headheight=1.75cm,headsep=0.55cm}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\newcommand{\titulo}[1]
{
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
\begin{center}
{\LARGE\bfseries\scshape{#1}}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
}

\newcommand{\palavraschave}[1]
{
\vspace*{-0.15cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
\begin{center}
{\small{\textbf{\scshape{Palavras-chave:}}\hspace*{0.2cm}\textrm{#1}.}}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
}

\newcommand{\autor}[3]
{
\begin{rmfamily}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c}
{\bfseries\large{#1}}\\
{\normalsize{#2}}\\
{\normalsize\itshape{#3}}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{rmfamily}
}

\newcommand{\N}{\mathds{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathds{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathds{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathds{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathds{C}}

\newcommand{\linhas}{\modulolinenumbers[1]\linenumbers}

\newenvironment{resumoportugues}
{\vspace*{0.25cm}\begin{center}\begin{small}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centerline{\bfseries\scshape{Resumo}\vspace*{-0.15cm}}\noindent}
{\end{minipage}\vspace*{0.25cm}\end{small}\end{center}}

\newenvironment{resumoingles}
{\begin{center}\begin{small}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centerline{\bfseries\scshape{Abstract}\vspace*{-0.15cm}}\noindent}
{\end{minipage}\vspace*{0.25cm}\end{small}\end{center}}

\newenvironment{prova}
{\begin{center}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centerline{\bfseries\sffamily{Demonstra\c{c}\~ao}}\begin{rmfamily}\vspace*{0.25cm}}
{\vspace*{0.25cm}\rightline{$\blacksquare$}\end{rmfamily}\end{minipage}\vspace*{0.25cm}\end{center}}

\newtheoremstyle{rmeef}
  {0.25cm}
  {0.25cm}
  {\itshape}
  {}
  {\bfseries\sffamily}
  {:}
  {.5em}
  {}

\theoremstyle{rmeef}

\newtheorem{definicao}{Defini\c{c}\~ao}
\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{lema}{Lema}
\newtheorem{corolario}{Corol\'ario}
\newtheorem{proposicao}{Proposi\c{c}\~ao}
\newtheorem{postulado}{Postulado}
\newtheorem{axioma}{Axioma}
\newtheorem{conjectura}{Conjectura}
\newtheorem{caso}{Caso}
\newtheorem{observacao}{Observa\c{c}\~ao}

\pagestyle{empty}



\allowdisplaybreaks

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathpzc}{OT1}{pzc}{m}{it}

\begin{document}

\linhas

\begin{teorema}
There's something wrong I'm not figuring out.
\end{teorema}

\begin{prova}
a

b

c

d

e

f

g

h

i

j

k

l

m

n

o

p

q

r

s

t

u

v

w

x

y

z

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10

11

12

13

14

15

16

17

18

19

20

21

22

23

24

25

26

27

28

29

30
\end{prova}

\end{document}
```

And here's the result:

[image]

[image]

If I keep adding lines on my proof they're not rendered anywhere, what am I doing wrong? I would like the proof to be split nicely into two or more pages.

Comment: Don't do proof envs like that. Minipages does not break. What is wrong with the standard proof env from amsthm?

Comment: Ohh, I didn't know that. For some reason these are the journal standards. I will use the standard proof environment.

Comment: I'll write an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prova environment is defined as a minipage, which generates a unbreakable block.

There are packages that can make breakable boxes. But in this case it seems more appropriate to just use the proof env from the `amsthm` package since you are already using that package.